# Adding a calendar to my website with multiple types of users

Tags: web, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm making a website for handling office hour queues that has 3 different types of users: guest, student, and instructor.

the instructors will be able to log in and enter the timings for their office hours for a specific course. and i want these office hours to show up in a calendar such that all the instructors teaching the same course can see the office hours.

i also want the students to be able to see this calendar for a specific course, so that they know when the office hours are.

i want to basically have a calendar for each course...and i'm not sure if that is possible?

i'm using java, javascript, html, and css to develop this website. does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely possible using the Google Calendar API.
You can:

1. Use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) for server-to-server communication towards Google Calendar API.
2. Insert calendars using [`Calendars: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert). Each of them would map to a different course.
3. Insert events using [`Events: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).
4. Query the events using [`Events: list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and [`Events: get`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).

Additionally, you will need somewhere to save which courses are the students enrolled to. You may use a database, or if you prefer using a Google solution, you may use a Google Sheets instance for that.

Comment: what type of service account should i make?

Comment: also does this method require the instructors/students to log in with their gmail accounts?

Comment: @SuryaSolanki There is only one "type" of service account, which you may learn more about [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). The users *could* use Google (if you wanted to) to authenticate with your platform. However, that is not necessary. You could have your own authentication method on your server and have the service account retrieve the appropriate data from the end user based on that. Hope that makes sense. Cheers